# How do I remove a node with e4x based on a property?

Tags: actionscript, e4x

I have a simple example

```
var myXML:XML =
<root>
    <element type="a">I am a</element>
    <element type="b">I am b</element>
</root>
;
```

I cant work out how I can programatically remove an element of a specific type

```
delete myXML.root.element.type['a'][0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a XML element by matching an attribute of that element, I believe you're looking for:

```
var index:int = myXML.element.(@type=="b").childIndex();
delete myXML.element[index];
```

Based upon your XML:

```
var myXML:XML =
    <root>
        <element type="a">I am a</element>
        <element type="b">I am b</element>
    </root>;
```

After calling this function, the XML would be:

```
<root>
  <element type="a">I am a</element>
</root>
```

Comment: delete myXML.element.(@type == "a")[0];